# Button with progress with steps

Tags: java, android-layout, android-button, android-progressbar

I need to create a button with progress with steps like the following screenshot and I have searched for the library to do that but I couldn't find it. Can anyone please send me the library or XML code?

[image]

Comment: You can try this  https://github.com/futuredapp/donut

Comment: @Swayangjit I need with steps like when click progress 1 fill, and when click again prog 2 fill , ....

Comment: you can explore that library.

Comment: @Swayangjit i explore it But it is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called ***State Progress Bar***. Check [this](https://github.com/kofigyan/StateProgressBar) library. Also read about it more from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/state-progressbar-in-android/). Hope this helps